# PHP show all connection

Tags: php, database, odbc

Really can't figure out how to word what I need...

I work with a site through SCP. And sometimes it crashes due to the database server fault. But actually I don't connect to that database. So I need to see all possible connections that my site can use. I found two files at `include path` that contain connection to server that faults, but my files don't include them. If I can give some more info please ask me.

All connections are made through `odbc_connect("DSN_NAME;host_address", $login, $pass)`

Comment: it will be good if you share some code

Comment: Are you using MySQL?

Comment: Without any code and MOST IMPORTANT any error messages, we can not help you. Your first task ALLWAYS has to be to make your error logs work!

Comment: @HendryTanaka: she is using oracle

Comment: 1. I'm a girl. 2. I use odbc driver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How did you find out that your SCP crashes because of database server fault? It shouldn't. I think the problem is not in database. By the way, MySQL allows to configure many connections, so I believe the problem is in something else.

Comment: I know that when one database server faults there is no access to my site, but my site actually doesn't connect to that database.

Comment: Use Zend Debug or xDebug and go through all steps when your site is loading, then you will find a place where he connects to DB.

Answer (score 0):

```
$con=mysqli_connect("example.com","peter","abc123","my_db");
```

Comment: she is using oracle connection, how come you ask her to use mysqli over oracle?